# How to create a filepath from console input in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, console-application, user-input, filepath, nsfilemanager

For my application, I need a user to be able to enter some input through the console, and that string, except uppercased, to be part of a path file.
I have the following code, but while everything appears to run smoothly, the file isn't actually created. I don't even get the error message through my if block.

```
#define DEBUGGER 1
NSLog (@"Username:");
char userInput[70];
fgets (userInput, sizeof userInput, stdin);
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
if (userInput [strlen(userInput) - 1] == '\n') //In case the input string has # characters plus \n
    userInput[strlen(userInput) - 1] = '\0'; //Plus '\0', the '\n' isn't added and the if condition is false
NSFileManager * fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString * string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: userInput];
NSString * stringUppercase = [string uppercaseString];
NSString * dirUsername = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Desktop/ProjAlleleData/Accounts/%@", stringUppercase.stringByExpandingTildeInPath];stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
#ifdef DEBUGGER
NSLog(@"DEBUGGER MESSAGE: Username Directory Path: %@", dirUsername);
#endif
if ([fm createDirectoryAtPath: dirUsername withIntermediateDirectories: YES attributes: nil error: NULL] != YES) {
    NSLog(@"Save File Creation Error.");
    return 1;}
```

Comment: I think the error (now that I included @Josh's) has to do with the pathname not being expanded properly... (I bet I'm going to find a whole bunch of randomly named directories in some folder close to root someday :P)

Comment: Confirmed that the error is about the tilde not being expanded in the pathname... I just replaced the tilde with /Users/whateverMyUserIsCalled and it worked.  I do need the tilde to be expanded though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString * dirUsername = [@"~/Desktop/MyFiles/%@", stringUppercase stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
```

should be:

```
NSString *dirUsername = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Desktop/MyFiles/%@", stringUppercase];
NSString *dirUsername2 = [dirUsername stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
```

or

```
NSString *dirUsername = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Desktop/MyFiles/%@", stringUppercase] stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
```

Your version was creating an array of the format string and the components, and assigning the array to dirUsername, but this version uses NSString stringWithFormat:.

(stringByAppendingPathComponent may be better, though: `[[@"~/Desktop/MyFiles" stringByAppendingPathComponent:stringUppercase] stringByExpandingTildeInPath];`)

Comment: I get an error pointing at stringByExpandingTildeInPath that says "expected :" when I do the solution you suggested.

Comment: Sorry, try that. It was `stringUppercase stringByExpandingTildeInPath`, which was missing a :, so it could be either `stringUppercase.stringByExpandingTildeInPath` or `[stringUppercase.stringByExpandingTildeInPath]`.

Comment: I accepted your answer :). For future users you might want to take out the period in your last statement (it is either [receiver message] or reciever.message, not both.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but please add in this line: NSString * dirUsername2 = [dirUsername stringByExpandingTildeInPath]; for future users, and remove the stringByExpandingTildeInPath from the first dirUsername. This is the only way to let the path have input AND expand the tilde that I could make work.

Comment: Updated with your suggestions